# how can i pass selected picklist value from component to apex class

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a picklist which is gatting records from one object now after selecting any value I want to pass the name of that record to my apex class, I know how to pass the id of selected record but how can I pass the name so that I can insert record using the selected value

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="RE_Customcaseregistration">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="SelectedValue" type="String"></aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="NewCase" type="Case"
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case',
                             'Subject': '',
                             'Description' : '',
                             'Comments':'',
                             'email__c' : ''}"/>
    <lightning:card title="" class="supportblock">
        <h1 class="slds-m-top_large slds-text-heading_medium">Customer Support</h1>
        <lightning:input aura:id="inputCmp" type="text" name="input1" label="Subject" required="true" value="{!v.NewCase.Subject}" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter a value"/>
        <lightning:select class="select-auto-width" aura:id="SelectPropertyRcrd" name="select" label="Select a Property" required="true" value="{!v.SelectedValue}" onchange="{!c.UpdateSelectoption}"> 
            <option value="choose">Choose one...</option> 
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="s">
                <option value="{!s.Id}">{!s.Name}</option>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
        <ui:inputTextArea  label="Description"   rows="5" value="{!v.NewCase.Description}"/>        
        <h1 class="slds-m-top_large slds-text-heading_medium">Additional Information</h1>
        <lightning:input  aura:id="inputCmp" type="text" name="input1" label="Additional comments" value="{!v.NewCase.Comments}" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter a value"/>
        <lightning:input aura:id="inputCmp" type="text" name="input1" label="Email"  required="true" value="{!v.NewCase.email__c}" messageWhenValueMissing="Enter value"/>
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit" onclick="{!c.createAccount}"  />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:-

```
    UpdateSelectoption : function(component, event, helper)
    {
 console.log("selected value");
        console.log("selected value", component.get("v.SelectedValue"));
        var selected=component.find("SelectPropertyRcrd").get("v.value");
        console.log("Selected PickList value" ,selected);
        var action = component.get("c.getvalue");
        console.log("selected value", component.get("v.SelectedValue"));
            action.setParams({ "SelectedValue" : selected });
            action.setCallback(this, function(response)
            {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === 'SUCCESS')
            {   
            //var list = response.getReturnValue();
            }  
            else if(state === 'ERROR')
            {
            alert('ERROR OCCURED.');
            }
            })

            $A.enqueueAction(action);
            },
```

Comment: i'm not able to get output can you please helpme out @sanketkumar

Comment: did you correct the setparams?

Comment: changed my this controller code please check my updated code once

Comment: you didnt correct it yet. can check my answer and correct the line

Comment: replace with method - added in answer

Comment: working fine thanks, alot @salesforce-sas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you are not getting any value in `SelectedValue` in below line (it will be undefined):

```
action.setParams({ "property" : SelectedValue });
```

corrected method (with correctly setting params) to below:

```
UpdateSelectoption : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.setValue");
    action.setParams({ "property" : component.get("v.SelectedValue") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS')
        {   
            //var list = response.getReturnValue();
        }  
        else if(state === 'ERROR')
        {
            alert('ERROR OCCURED.');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you option tag in lightning:select as below:-

```
<option text="{!s.Name}" value="{!s.Id}"/>
```

You can get the name of selected name of lightning:select component as below:-

```
UpdateSelectoption: function (component, evt, helper) {
var value= component.find('SelectPropertyRcrd').get('v.text');
}
```